# Is it possible to Make a Request Parameter optional in retrofit2?

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am making a Multipart request with Retrofit2, where I upload an image and some text data. File part is optional here, that means user may or may not choose an image. Is there a way to make any parameter optional in Retrofit ?

I tried like this,if file mandatory below code working,

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), file);
                fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.getName(), requestBody);

@Multipart
    @POST("url")
    Call<Response> create(
            @Part("name") RequestBody name,
            @Part("mail") RequestBody mail,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part image
    );
```

Comment: You can make two methods with different signature (one with image parameter and the other without it) and if the user upload an image you call your first method otherwise you call the second

Comment: what do u mean ? I didn't understand u

Answer (score 0):

@Rgv just pass **null** value for Multipart.part image  value when requesting API. It's done . I m using in that way. Hope this help some one. Look below code where I have passed null value for file image. and pass image file when there is file for profile image .

```
request = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getMyApi().updateProfileAPI(
                    UtilsClass.convertStringToRequestbody(name),
                    UtilsClass.convertStringToRequestbody(email),null);
```